# Infopath 2003: Enabled browser forms

Tags: forms, browser, service, infopath

I was wondering whether forms designed through infopath 2003 have the capability to be opened and fille out through a browser (using infopath forms services). While looking at the Tools --> Form Options, I could not find any related 'browser-enabled' check box. Can this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InfoPath 2003 with Sharepoint 2003 does not support viewing and filling out forms in a browser, but Sharepoint 2007 and Sharepoint 2010 do support browser forms.

Sharepoint 2007 does support InfoPath 2003 compatibility though. So you can use InfoPath 2007 to open an InfoPath 2003 form and publish it to a Sharepoint 2007 page.

Note: I know this question is old, but it is a good question.